# Esperar valor de return en funciones recursivas

Tags: php

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
    class almacenar{
        private $lista_imagenes;
        private $indice;
        private $total_imagenes;
        private $links;
        function __construct($lista_imagenes){
            $this->lista_imagenes = $lista_imagenes;
            $this->indice = 0;
            $this->total_imagenes = count($lista_imagenes);
            $this->links = array();
        }
        function subir_imagenes(){          
            $url_archivo = '../../img/subidas/' . $this->lista_imagenes[$this->indice];
//aqui omito algunas lineas donde valido la existencia del archivo
            (new clsbucket)->upload(
                $archivo,
                [
                    'name' => 'uploads/app/' . $nombre_archivo,
                    'resumable' => false,
                    'uploadProgressCallback' => self::finalizar_subida($nombre_archivo)
                ]
            );
            return $this->links;
        }
        function finalizar_subida($nombre_archivo){
            $this->indice = $this->indice + 1;
            $this->links[] = $nombre_archivo;
            if ($this->indice < $this->total_imagenes) {
                self::subir_imagenes();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Cuando ejecuto la llamada a mi código:

```
$arraydemo = array('12_03_2019_17_37_35.jpg', '12_03_2019_15_29_46.jpg', '12_03_2019_15_26_39.jpg');

    $subir = new clsGoogleStorage($arraydemo);
    $info = $subir->subir_imagenes();

    echo json_encode($info);
```

obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
["12_03_2019_17_37_35.jpg","12_03_2019_15_29_46.jpg","12_03_2019_15_26_39.jpg"]
```

A decir verdad ese es el resultado esperado, pero ¿porqué estoy obteniendo ese resultado?, ¿porqué espera a que el callback y todas las llamadas recursivas se finalize antes de devolver el valor en el `return $this->links;`?, ¿siempre obtendré el valor esperado?, ¿si se desean subir demasiadas imágenes, se corre el riesgo de colapsar?.
Quizá no estoy formulando bien mi pregunta, o se presta a opiniones, pero soy nuevo en php y según mi lógica `return $this->links;` debería ejecutarse inmediatamente después de `(new clsbucket)->upload(...);`.

Comment: Yo al menos esto: `(new clsbucket)->upload(` no lo reconozco como código PHP válido. En todo lo demás que dices, depende, de muchas cosas: del servidor, de los recursos que tengas, de la velocidad de la conexión, de la cantidad de usuarios que usen el código, etc. En cuanto a si algo debe estar antes o después, o no debe estar,  o ser cambiado por otra cosa, también depende de miles de situaciones. Veo difícil en ese sentido dar una respuesta a tu pregunta, porque son cosas subjetivas que podrían tener varias respuestas y para responder habría que conocer más detalles.

Comment: @A.Cedano `(new clsbucket)->upload(` es un código perfectamente válido en PHP. Es una simple expresión, que evalúa como una variable anónima (una `RValue Reference` en C++11). En todo lo demas, **no estoy de acuerdo**: PHP es síncrono y secuencial *desde siempre*.

Comment: @Trauma pues se me hace difícil comprender qué es lo que hace ese código exactamente en la parte: `(new clsbucket)->upload(
                $archivo,
                [
                    'name' => 'uploads/app/' . $nombre_archivo,` es la primera vez que veo algo así.

Comment: @A.Cedano Simplemente, crea una variable sin nombre, anónima, instancia de la clase `clsbucket`. En cuanto la crea, llama a su método `upload( )` con los argumentos pasados. La variable desaparece, deja de existir, en cuanto se retorna de esa llamada a `upload( )`. Es una forma de *ahorrar* una variable cuando solo la vamos a usar por poco tiempo, como en ese caso. No te puedo dar información sobre eficiencia, optimizaciones y demás, tengo el PHP *oxidadillo* :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jejeje ... te estás confundiendo **con JavaScript** :-D

PHP es totalmente **secuencial** y **síncrono**; cualquier operación que realices **detiene el código** hasta que dicha operación finalice.

> ¿porqué espera a que el callback ...

Olvídate de *callbacks*; ese concepto **no es aplicable**. ¡ Esto es PHP !

> ¿si se desean subir demasiadas imágenes, se corre el riesgo de colapsar?.

Colapsar no ... simplemente, si el intérprete nota que tu *script* tarda **demasiado tiempo** en ejecutarse, lo detendrá. Este tiempo máximo de ejecución se establece en `php.ini`:

> **max_execution_time:**
>   Este valor establece el tiempo máximo en segundos que se permite ejecutar antes de que el analizador termine. Esto ayuda a prevenir que scripts mal escritos bloqueen el servidor. El valor por defecto es 30. Cuando se ejecuta PHP desde la línea de comandos el valor por defecto es 0.

Por supuesto, esto **tiene un coste**: por cada petición, PHP ejecuta tu código y no para hasta que lo termina ... **sin poder atender a otras peticiones**. Como consecuencia, no es lo *óptimo* para entornos con mucha carga: no tendrás más remedio que aumentar el hardware.

Esto **no es literalmente cierto**; los propios servidores WEB y el servicio `fpm` distribuyen las peticiones entre cierto número de hilos o procesos, pero la secuencia es la misma: terminar con una petición antes de aceptar otra.